# how to add external string to the output of a query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to add a string to the output of a query, for example:
my table tab1 has a column, named col1. col1 has 5 distinct values: d1, d2, d3, d4, d5.

with the following query I got the distinct values:

```
select distinct col1 from tab1
```

I want to add 'all' to the output of this query. So the expected output will be as follows:

```
col1
all
d1
d2
d3
d4
d5
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
select 'all' as col1
union all
select distinct col1 from tab1
```